# Windows Phone InkPresenter Alternative?

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I'm creating a Windows Phone 8.1 universal app but it seems the `InkPresenter` type is no more.

Are there any alternatives builtin or 3rd party?

What is the new way that Microsoft wants us to work with ink in universal apps?

Comment: I don't think this question should be closed for the reason given, it's not really asking for a recommendation, rather an objective alternative to a namespace that's missing. `InkPresenter` is not available for universal apps but you could create your own version similar to what's explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14276909/alternative-to-inkpresenter) (depending on how complex you need it to be).

Comment: This example is for win phone 8 doesn't work for 8.1